# How to calculate standard deviation and use three-sigma rule for couple variables?

Tags: measure-theory, standard-deviation

Generally, I have the following data:

```
CampaingOne 49%
CampaingTwo 41%
```

I need to use the [three-sigma rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68-95-99.7_rule) and check if the second value is in the interval [- 2 sigma;+ 2 sigma].

As I have read, the sigma value according this rule is as follows:

```
1 sigma - 66.7% 
2 sigma - 95%
3 sigma - 99%
```

So, what I am doing is to check how many percent is the score of CampaingTwo from the score of CampaingOne using the following [calculator](http://www.csgnetwork.com/csgpercent.html).

For example:

```
41 from 49 is 83.6734693877551%
```

And now because the result is little then "2 sigma" I am concluding that it's not in the interval.

Anyway, I am almost sure that what I am doing is far away from the truth and need some help in this.

Could anyone give me a simple example of what calculations I need to perform?

Comment: The sigma here is the standard deviation. For a sample of two, the standard deviation is one-half the absolute value of their difference. Each value is exactly $1$ sigma away from their mean, $45\%$.

Comment: So, the standard deviation in my case is "|A-B|/2" or "49-41/2=4"? I need to have in the mean the first value - 49% and to calculate is the 41% 2 sigma or more away from it? Does this make sense?

Comment: Since the standard deviation is calculated from the mean, usually the three sigma rule is also based on the mean, that is $45\%$. If there is another mean, there must be other data and the standard deviation must take that into account. However, if you are only given those two data points and you are asked to find the distance between them in terms of sigma, then it would be $2$.

Comment: Yes, I will be given only two data points and need the distances between them in terms of sigma - you said this is 2. Could you write me an answer with the calculations, please? I'm sure this is what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will consolidate my comments here.

Since the standard deviation ($\sigma$) is calculated from the mean of the data, usually the three sigma rule is also based on the mean of the data.

From the data given, the mean is $\dfrac{.49+.41}{2}=.45$.

The standard deviation would be $\sigma=\sqrt{\dfrac{(.49-.45)^2+(.41-.45)^2}{2}}=.04$.

If there is different mean, there must be other data, which might mean a different $\sigma$. Otherwise, you can compute the distance between the two samples in terms of their standard deviation using their difference ($.49-.41$) the value if $\sigma$ computed above.

Comment: Thanks,but how you calculated that "However, if you are only given those two data points and you are asked to find the distance between them in terms of sigma, then it would be 2."?

Comment: For two data points, $a$ and $b$, the mean is $\frac{a+b}{2}$ and the standard deviation is $\frac{|a-b|}{2}$. The distance between the data points is $|a-b|$. What is the distance between the data points divided by the standard deviation?

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient and time. I am really sorry, that my questions may somehow sounds silly, but I have not done any mathematics for 3 years and found reading and understanding formulas in the net very difficult. That's why I need an example. Anyway, thank you again.